# How do I conditionally parse formatting with Thymeleaf?

Tags: thymeleaf

Is there an alternate way I can get this to process with Thymeleaf?  Thymeleaf doesn't like the open  tag, but I want to only render it for ROLE_A.

```
 <span sec:authorize="hasRole('ROLE_A')">      
      <div class="col-xs-10">
 </span>
 bunch of text not specific to ROLE_A
 <span sec:authorize="hasRole('ROLE_A')">
        custom text specific to ROLE_A
      </div>
 </span>
```

I tried using

```
 <sec:authorize="hasRole('ROLE_A')">
```

and

```
 <div sec:authorize="hasRole('ROLE_A')">.
```

The former also doesn't run due to the same open tag issue and the latter is mixing up the closed div tags.

I have numerous blocks like this, so duplicating sections for different roles is not a great solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not in the style you want. You need to close those elements.

My advice is then consider using fragments and load them as required with the needed data/

That way you reuse existing code thus making it cleaner and smaller.

For more examples and way you can do the above check out the Thymeleaf page http://www.thymeleaf.org/doc/springsecurity.html.

Comment: So what exactly would fall into a fragment and what would fall into the controller?  Can you please provide an example based on this block?  Maybe it's something simple I'm not seeing.

Comment: I can't provide it to be honest as depending on how you setup your MVC and logic it could vary, its also opion based. All i can recommend is review fragments http://www.thymeleaf.org/doc/usingthymeleaf.html#template-layout and see how you can break up yor code in logical sections (ones that require RoleA and ones that don't etc.)

Comment: After looking at this, I don't see any way even with fragments to do this without duplicating sections.

Comment: I agree there definitely would be duplication, but not as much of it. Your other option is to create the html within the controller e.g. string text = "<div id='junk>stuff</div>' and then pass it as variables. Something i seriously don't recommend you do.

Comment: Agreed.  Appreciate the help.  Going work on this a bit more to see whether there's a clever solution.

Comment: Glad to help. Im having lot of experimentation with this but it's tough.

Comment: Accepting your response since "no direct solution right now" is probably the best answer.